# Jquery email validation fire agian after fix

Tags: jquery

When email address is not valid its working fine at the IF. Then when I go and put in a valid email the ELSE should fire and clear error div which its not.

```
<SCRIPT>
$(document).ready(function(){

$("#email").blur(function (){
var emailReg = /^([\w-\.]+@([\w-]+\.)+[\w-]{2,4})?$/;
if (!emailReg.test(email.value)) {
    $("#theErrorDivID").html('Email Address Is Not Valid!');
    $('#email').css("background-color","red");
    $('#email').focus();
}
else {
    $("#theErrorDivID").html = "";
}

 })


  });
 </SCRIPT>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$("#theErrorDivID").html = "";
```

should be

```
$("#theErrorDivID").html("");
```

Answer (score 0):

**[Demo here](http://jsfiddle.net/7SWza/)**

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#email").blur(function () {
        var emailReg = /^([\w-\.]+@([\w-]+\.)+[\w-]{2,4})?$/;
        if (!emailReg.test($("#email").val())) {
            $("#theErrorDivID").html('Email Address Is Not Valid!');
            $('#email').css("background-color", "red");
            $('#email').focus();
        } else {
            $("#theErrorDivID").html("");
        }

    })
});
```

In the if you are trying to `.test()` `email.value`, you should have `$("#email").val()` (unless email was a defined variable before); In the else you should have `.html("")` instead of `.html = "";`